# Syntax for adding a parameter to function(e) and then to regex

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax, parameters

First of all - sorry about the general confusion - whenever I have to deal with `JS` I feel out of my element ..

I have a small script for duplicating fields , which was "hacked" from several other scripts - but is working great with no problems ..

The issue is that I want to reuse this script with different class names, on several istances on a page .

So basically , I need to pass a parameter to be regexe´d later (in the code it is hardcoded as `"features"` But I need as a Variable `"className"`).

My Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $.fn.addEle = function(e) {
            // do not re-load anything
            e.preventDefault();
            // count elements to set new id and name-attributes
            var num     = $(e.target).parent().parent().find('p.feature-element').length;
            // set the new id- and name-attributes integer
            var newNum  = parseInt(num) + parseInt(1);
            // create our new form-fields
            var newElem = $(e.target).parent().prev().clone();
            // iterate over each input field
            newElem.find('input').each(function(index) {
                // find and replace ID in our clone with new id
                var idRegExp = new RegExp( '(id_)(\\d+)' ,["i"]);
                $(this).attr( 'id', $(this).attr('id').replace( idRegExp , "id_"+newNum ) );
                                // find and replace NAME in our clone with new name-id
                                var nameRegExp = new RegExp( '\\[features\\]\\[(\\d+)\\]' ,["i"]);
                $(this).attr( 'name', $(this).attr('name').replace( nameRegExp , "[features]["+newNum+"]" ) );
                // empty value
                $(this).val('');
            });
            // add form-fields to the DOM
            $( newElem ).insertBefore( $(e.target).parent() );
        }
        // add element on button click
        $('.repeat-parent').live("click", function(e) {   $.fn.addEle(e);   });
    });
    </script>
```

Now, I am a `PHP` person, and as much as I tried, never really got the `JS` syntax right .
So simply put - how to pass a paramater to a function of type function(`e`) and later how to regex a parameter ( and not a string ) ?

Summing up -

- 1st problem :

Qhat is the right syntax to  add a parameter to such a function ?
As I understand it , the `e` in `$.fn.addEle = function(e)` just stands for `event`.
So how can I add a parameter , say `className` , something like :

turning this :

```
$.fn.addEle = function(e){...}

    $('.repeat-parent').live("click", function(e) {   $.fn.addEle(e);   });
```

into this :

```
$.fn.addEle = function(e,className){...}

    $('.repeat-parent').live("click", function(e) {   $.fn.addEle(e,className);   });
```

In PHP , I would just add a parameter :

function `my_function()` to function `my_function($my_parameter='value')`, and then call `my_function('my_new_value')`

- 2nd problem is with regex in these lines:

  `var nameRegExp = new RegExp( '\\[features\\]\\[(\\d+)\\]' ,["i"]);`
     `$(this).attr( 'name', $(this).attr('name').replace( nameRegExp , "[features]["+newNum+"]" ) );`

how to turn it into this, where `className` is actually a parameter and not a string to be searched ...

```
 var nameRegExp = new RegExp( '\\["className"\\]\\[(\\d+)\\]' ,["i"]);
                        $(this).attr( 'name', $(this).attr('name').replace( nameRegExp , "['className']["+newNum+"]" ) );
```

( I think I also got all the quotes wrong , but inside regex it is quite confusing..)

Comment: Does your example of how to add the parameter not work? What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: I am not entirely sure - the script is binding to a button, and when it fails - the button submits and going to another page ... I think the error is : missing ( after argument list . ( syntax error - pointer is in regex where I put the variable inside regex ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain what the issue is with your first question.  I put togethor a quick test that appears to work:

```
jQuery.fn.addEle = function(e, temp){
  alert(temp);
}
e = 'event placeholder';
jQuery.fn.addEle(e, 'test');
```

I'm running this in the chrome console and it is alerting fine.  It may have something to do with attempting to use the 'this' variable. That is not available unless you send it as an argument.

On to your second question.  If you create a regex object and send that as the variable in your function you can pullthe source out and use it in a new one.  that explanation doesnt even makes sense in my mind so here is an example:

Your original example (simplified to save space) reads like this

```
jQuery.fn.addEle = function(e){
  var nameRegExp = new RegExp( '\\[features\\]\\[(\\d+)\\]' ,["i"]);
  $(this).attr( 'name', $(this).attr('name').replace( nameRegExp , "[features]["+newNum+"]" ) );
}
```

Now I wasn't certain if you wanted to pass the name as a string then use the string as a part of the regex or if you wanted a regular expression to select the function name, so I did both.

This first one takes two new arguments, tempThis(to give you access to the 'this' object) and className.  ClassName is added to the regex as a string

```
$.fn.addEle = function(e, tempThis, className){
    console.log('running the first function')
    var nameRegExp = new RegExp( '\\[' + className + '\\]\\[(\\d+)\\]' ,["i"]);
    newNum = 2;
    $(tempThis).attr( 'name', $(tempThis).attr('name').replace( nameRegExp , "["+className+"]["+newNum+"]" ) );
}

classNameArg = 'class-name';
$('.repeat-parent').live("click", function(e) {
    $.fn.addEle(e, this, classNameArg);
});
```

The second function takes a regular expression object as an argument then pulls the source and adds it to your regex.  Be wrned, you cannot use the 'className' variable in this example as a part of your replace because it is a regex.  Maybe add another argument called classNameReadable?

```
$.fn.addEle2 = function(e, tempThis, className){
    console.log('running the second function')
    var nameRegExp = new RegExp( '\\[' + className.source + '\\]\\[(\\d+)\\]' ,["i"]);
    newNum = 2;
    $(tempThis).attr( 'name', $(tempThis).attr('name').replace( nameRegExp , "[features]["+newNum+"]" ) );
}
classNameRegex = /class\sname[0-9]+/;
$('.repeat-parent-second').live("click", function(e) {
    $.fn.addEle2(e, this, classNameRegex);
});
```

A js fiddle of the above is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/TueQa/3/

Comment: DUDE ... your solution ( first ) works like a charm ! simple and elegant. Bravo.